# proving point wise convergence but no uniform convergence on f

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let f$_n$: E → $R$ be continuous functions for 1 ≤ n ≤ N. Let a$_k$$^n$ be N convergent sequences of numbers and assume $\lim_{k \to inf}$ a$_k$$^n$  = a$_n$. Let f = $\sum_{n=1}^N$a$_n$f$_n$.

I am looking at $\sum_{n=1}^N$ a$_k$$^n$f$_n$. I am pretty sure that it converges pointwise to f but I don't think it converges uniformly to f. However, I am having trouble proving the point wise convergence to f and cannot think of a good counterexample for the uniform convergence to f. Any help would be great!

Comment: For pointwise convergence, fix $x\in E$, and look at $$\left\lvert \sum_{n=1}^N {a_k}^n f_n(x) - \sum_{n=1}^N a_n f_n(x)\right\rvert.$$ Estimate that in a natural way. Then you see what property of $\{ f_n(x) : 1 \leqslant n \leqslant N\}$ you use to show pointwise convergence. That tells you a sufficient condition for the uniform convergence, and will allow you to construct examples where the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: hmmm I've been playing around with that notion, but I can't seem to see how it is point wise convergent

Comment: Into what form did you manipulate it to obtain an estimate?

Comment: I still can't figure out how to manipulate it